# Finding basis of quotient vector space $V/W$ not by extending a basis of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ a subspace. I want to find a basis for $V/W$ without giving first a basis of $W$, extending it to a basis of $V$ and taking the classes of the added vectors (the standard way to do it).

Suppose $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Is the set of *distinct* classes in $V/W$ of the vectors $v_i$ a basis for $V/W$?

I can see this is a set of generators of $V/W$, but I can't prove linear  independence.

Comment: That set can't be a basis for the quotient space since the quotient space has lower dimension. It will span, so it contains a basis. You can use any method that finds an independent subset of a spanning set.

Comment: @EthanBolker It *can* be a basis for very particular bases $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, but in general it will not be. For example, extending a basis $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ for $W$ by $v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n$ to a basis for $V$, setting $v_i:=v_n+w_i$ yields a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ for $V$ with the desired property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $V=\Bbb{R}^2$ with the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $W=\{(v_1,v_2)\in V:\ v_1=v_2\}$. Then the two standard basis vectors map to two distinct elements of $V/W$, which is one-dimensional, so they cannot be linearly independent.

A more general and perhaps simpler example; extend a basis for $W$ to a basis for $V$. Then all basis vectors of $W$ are mapped to $0$ in $V/W$, so the resulting set cannot be linearly independent.